# IO::Prompter echo "stars" not working as intended

Tags: perl

I took some Perl code I already used last year on a fresh installation on Ubuntu 18.04.
For "some" reason `IO::Prompter` does not properly echo the stars, as you can see in the example.

```
user@host:~$ sudo cpan install IO::Prompter
IO::Prompter is up to date (0.004015).

user@host:~$ perl -MIO::Prompter -E 'say prompt "foo: ", -echo=>"*"'
foo: topSecret
topSecret

user@host:~$ perl --version
This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

What am I overlooking?
I have no "fancy" setups in this fresh VM.
Just installed missing libs via `cpan` and use the shipped system perl.

Any help appreciated. Also alternative module suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the documentation for `-echo`, we find the following:

> Note that this option is only available when the Term::ReadKey module is installed. If it is used when that module is not available, a warning will be issued.

So, simply install Term::ReadKey.

And always use `use strict; use warnings;`! That said, the warning could be better. `Warning: next input will be in plaintext` would be more useful if it explained what that is so.

Comment: you just saved my evening sir. I just had `use v5.22` and forgot `use warnings` in this script.